# Does ReactDOM wait for the onload event to start rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, single-page-application

Say I have a client rendered React app rendered by ReactDOM,

```
<body>

<div id="root"></div>
<script src="/mybundle.js"></script> <!-- rendering happens here -->

<script async src='https://cdn.third-party.com/segment.js'></script>
<script async src='https://cdn.third-party.com/google_analytics.js'></script>
<script async src='https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'></script>
<script async src='https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'></script>
<!-- etc.. various other 3rd party trackers and crap we have to load -->

</body>
```

My understanding is that these third party libraries will delay the `onload` event until their various scripts are loaded even if `async` is specified.

Will this delay rendering of my react app?

I've tested this and our first meaningful paint occurs about 2 seconds faster on a throttled machine if I remove all third party javascript. These libraries all make the case that they don't slow down your site, but experimentally they definitely do.

Performance with 3rd party libraries,
[image]

Performance with all 3rd party libraries removed,
[image]

Is there some way I can load these third party libraries without it ruining the performance of my client rendered single page app?

I know.. 2.75 seconds is still horrendously slow. I'm trying to find quick wins before undertaking a major rewrite.

Comment: HI I had the same question recently I found this article by Addy Osmani useful https://addyosmani.com/blog/script-priorities/ perhaps some of your external scripts could be deferred

Comment: are all scripts are independent or dependent on each and everyone?

Comment: What happens if you swap `async` attribute with `defer` or may be add `defer` tag to it, does that help out?

Comment: These are all at the end of the body tag. I was under the impression `defer` does nothing when used there, but I'll try it.

The scripts are somewhat independent. They load analytics trackers that are used to record client events, but that's definitely not critical & we should be able to find a way to delay using them.

Answer (score -1):

My sources indicate that it does not wait for the onload event.

**Link Sources:**

- [ReactDOM - Offial Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html)
- [React - Edureka Blog](https://www.edureka.co/blog/react-components/)

**Image Sources:**

[image]

Comment: Not sure where your sources indicate that. I see no mention of the onload event anywhere in there. That diagram says nothing about the onload event either? Not sure how you're drawing this conclusion.

Comment: the "pre-commit" phase reads the DOM, also the commit phase works with the DOM

Comment: see, [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/90ka1j/using_windowonload_with_react/)

Comment: [link 2](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/how-to-integrate-react-into-existing-app/)